# Codeigniter: Best way to limit the access

Tags: php, codeigniter

Okay now I am on the flow of development of my application using Codeigniter (start to love it :))

My entire system will be only available for the logged in users and as soon as they will come system will take them to the log in page.

Now I am starting to limit the access for different user groups. So my big question is which method will be good to perform the logged in check?

- Perform check on every controller methods?
- Can directly write in header.php view file and perform check and redirect if needed?

Since admin and front-end both will be limited to access, based on user role and nothing will be accessible to the guest.

**Edit:**

Extreemly sorry I forgot to mention that I am using `Ion Auth` library for authentication. Also I have written few helpers based on `ion auth` to make life easier.

Comment: please see my answer @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21451041/how-to-store-login-time-into-my-mysql-table-using-code-igniter

it contain an example of MY_CONTROLLER and auth; im sure its not what u need exactly but it give u a small picture of how things can happen;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an extended core controller called `MY_Controller.php` in the core directory, the prefix must match your configured prefix in config.php however.

In `MY_Controller`, you could create a function called `is_logged_in` which checks if the login session (if it's session based) exists and is valid.

In every controller which requires a valid login session, in the construct method you would just say `if(!$this->is_logged_in()) { redirect('/login'); }` for example.

The reason I prefer a method like this as opposed to doing a session check in each individual controller is that if, say, the name of your logged in session index changes, you only have to modify the logged in check in one central place.

Comment: okay what I understood is overriding core CI_Controller with MY_Controller and in `__construct()` I perform check for logged in user?

Comment: Exactly. What I actually said was have an `is_logged_in` function, but I've just realized you said every page is for logged in users only, so your check can actually be in the constructor of `MY_Controller`.

Comment: Okay cool let me try now

Comment: Super cool and perfect way to do.. working perfect the way I want...thanks a lot..

Answer (score 0):

If you do it in your `header.php` you will have to use multiple `header.php`'s to do your checks. The way I do it is by using codeigniter's built in `session` library and then use:

```
if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'){
    $this->model_name->function();
    $this->load->view("header");
}else{
    redirect("login", "refresh");
}
```

You can do something like this:

```
$array = array(
    'logged_in'           => true,
    'admin'               => true,
    'some_other_thing'    => false
);

$this->session->set_userdata('admin'. $array);
```

Comment: I am really sorry just updated question. Forgot to mention that using ion auth library for authenticaiton